# Conditional formatting giving AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Tags: conditional-formatting, xlsxwriter

I am trying to run a conditional format for one of my column in excel using xlswriter. I want to have the blank rows in the column in a certain format. Below I have attached the code snippet. But it is giving me an AttributeError:'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'.

```py
format1 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#FFC7CE',
                               'font_color': '#9C0006'})

worksheet.conditional_format('G:H', {'type': 'no_blanks','format':format1})
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column notation 'G:H' isn't supported in this case. You will need to specify the full range like:

```py
worksheet.conditional_format('G1:H1048576',
                             {'type': 'no_blanks','format':format1})
```

Or with row-column notation:

```py
worksheet.conditional_format(0, 5, 1048575, 6,
                             {'type': 'no_blanks','format':format1})
```